# Pseudo-isotopy of a surface implies isotopy?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth compact connected surface, possibly with boundary. Let $f:M \rightarrow M$ be a diffeomorphism that fixes the boundary.

Assume that $f$ is pseudo-isotopic to the identity map, i.e. that there exists a diffeomorphism $F:M \times I \rightarrow M \times I$ that fixes $M \times \{0\}$ and $\partial M \times I$, and satisfy that $F|_{M \times \{1\} } = f \times 1$.

Is $f$ necessarily smoothly isotopic to the identity map? Is there a counter example?

I have only found a counter example in higher dimensions (see this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249398/easiest-example-where-pseudo-isotopy-fails-to-be-the-same-as-isotopy), or the [original paper](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/Papers/ConcordanceSpaces.pdf)), and I have not found any relevant references. It seems plausible to me that this will turn out to be true in low dimensions, but my intuition of pseudo-isotopies is somewhat limited.

Comment: They are homotopic rel boundary, hence, isotopic.

Comment: Oh, you mean by Epstein? I missed this somehow

Comment: Right............

Comment: Maybe a somewhat unrelated question, but, when you refer to Epstein's result as a smooth result, do you mean "it is straight forward to generalize his proof to smooth isotopies' (as Boldsen's preprint demonstrates)?

Comment: Anyway, feel free to write the comment as an answer and I'll accept it ofc

Comment: Smooth theory was worked out by Earle and Eells using the Beltrami equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert my comments to an answer: Pseudo-isotopy  implies (boundary-preserving) homotopy. The latter (in dimension 2) implies smooth isotopy. See for instance

*Earle, C. J.; Eells, J.*, [**A fibre bundle description of Teichmüller theory**](https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214428816), J. Differ. Geom. 3, 19-43 (1969). [ZBL0185.32901](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0185.32901).

*Earle, C. J.; Schatz, A.*, [**Teichmüller theory for surfaces with boundary**](https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214429381), J. Differ. Geom. 4, 169-185 (1970). [ZBL0194.52802](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0194.52802).